# When does $\ker(M) = Span( I - M^{+}M)$ ? Always?

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

Let $M$ be an $m \times n$ matrix, where the rows are linearly independent.

Let $M^{+}$ be the pseudo-inverse of $M$ (which I think is $M^{+}  =M^T\left(MM^T\right)^{-1}$, at least when $m\leq n$).

Does $\ker(M) = Span(I - M^{+}M)$? Sometimes? Always? Under what circumstances?

Context: I am a musician working on an algorithmic composition system. I am not a student or a mathematician. This is not homework.

Comment: [Always](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Projectors)

Comment: Given that you are not a mathematician, you might not be entirely sure of notational conventions, but you should note that $\ker(M)$ is a vector subspace, whereas $I-M^+M$ is a linear transformation (a particular kind of function). It would be more correct to say $\Pi_{\ker(M)} = I-M^+M$, where $\Pi_S$ is the orthogonal projection onto a subspace $S$.

Comment: I fixed it, I think. Is it correct to say Ker(M) = Span(N) for appropriate matrices M and N? I.e., I'm equating the subspaces.